# Azure Stream Analytics - Identify common data across the multiple data sets

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

I am capturing data from multiple sources with Azure Events hub and send to Azure Stream Analytics. These sources have some common data points.
Ex :

- Source 1 : PNR No
- Source 2 : PNR No

[image]

How can identify the common data across these multiple data sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that the multiple sources are ingested in a single event hub? I suppose there is a field SourceId that allows to identify where a data point is coming from?

If it's the case, you can use [Common Table Expressions (WITH)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/with-azure-stream-analytics?toc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fstream-analytics%2Ftoc.json&bc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json) to scope these sources, and [join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/join-azure-stream-analytics?toc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fstream-analytics%2Ftoc.json&bc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json) between them.

```
WITH 
  SourceA AS (
    SELECT * FROM Input WHERE SourceId = 'A'
  ),
  SourceB AS (
    SELECT * FROM Input WHERE SourceId = 'B'
  )

SELECT
  A.*,
  B.*
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B 
  ON A.[Pnr NO] = B.[Pnr NO]
  AND DATEDIFF(second,A,B) BETWEEN 0 AND 60
```

**Note that this is not a universal pattern**. It solves a specific business problem where we need to find a matching event for A in B (`FROM A LEFT JOIN B`), that happens in the following 60 seconds (`DATEDIFF(second,A,B) BETWEEN 0 AND 60`).

There are [lots of different patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-stream-analytics-query-patterns) to apply here depending on the specific scenario you are building for. For some, analytics functions (like [last](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/last-azure-stream-analytics?toc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fstream-analytics%2Ftoc.json&bc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json)) should be used instead of joins.

If you elaborate on your need I may be able to find the right pattern.